# Javascript Arrays and Objects

Tags: javascript

How Can I do an array of some data type in Javascript?, I have read about arrays and objects but I haven't found what I exactly looking for:

I just want to do:

```
person {name, lastname, age};

PersonsArray [n] of person;
```

do loops on it, and set values

```
PersonsArray[0].name = ...;
PersonsArray[0].lastname = ...;
PersonsArray[0].age= ...;
```

thank you

Comment: You don't declare any types in JS. Just create an array and fill it.

Comment: You are looking for the wrong language feature. JavaScript doesn't work like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a array

```
var PersonsArray=[];
```

Then push your object to it

```
PersonsArray.push({name:'ab', lastname:'bc', age:20});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/hb6mb514/)

Or you can try this

```
var PersonsArray=[];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  PersonsArray[i]={};
  PersonsArray[i].name = "ab";
  PersonsArray[i].lastname = "bc";
  PersonsArray[i].age= 20;

}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/jj3jabth/1/)**

Comment: Can I access to the fields like in C?, for example PersonsArray[0].name, PersonsArray[0].lastname

Comment: If the index has data . yes you can. i create a fiddle for you . check this : http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/hb6mb514/ @user4216713

Comment: @user4216713 -- you are looking for associative array....which **BTW** JS doesnot support but you can use object as associative array ---- check this blog http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array and iterate through it like this:

```
var personArray = [];

var person = { name: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 23 };

personArray.push(person);

// enumerate array
personArray.forEach(function(p) {
    p.name += "2";
    alert(p.name);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I can add new person that way, but what if i want to change the value of a field in some function, personArray[0].field?, like in C.

Comment: @user4216713 - It's just `personArray[0].name = "Bob";`  I'd suggest it would be a lot more efficient for you to you go through a basic Javascript tutorial rather than asking basic syntax questions one at a time here.

Comment: Why would you use `[].forEach.call`?

Comment: @torazaburo I improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also build an object like this**

```
var Person={firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe",age:"20"}
```

This object has three properties

```
firstname
lastname
age
```

You can also change any of the above if needed, for example

```
Person.firstname="Mark"
```

**Looping to find the name for each property**

```
for(i in Person){console.log(i)}
```

The above will print to the console all the properties of the object

```
firstname
lastname
age
```

**Create many Persons identity as you like by creating an object constructor function**

```
function Person(firstname,lastname,age){
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age
}
```

**Create an object using your constructor function**

```
var Michael=new Person("Michael","Williams","23")
```

**Using console.log to check whether your object properties are correct**

```
console.log(Michael.firstname)
```